# $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} f(\xi_{n})\Delta x_{i}$ notation explanation

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, riemann-sum

This task comes from my text book, can someone help me solve it, please?

> Let $$R_{n} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} f(\xi_{n})\Delta x_{i} =
> > f(\xi_{1})\Delta x_{1} + f(\xi_{2})\Delta x_{2} + f(\xi_{3})\Delta
>  x_{3} + ...+f(\xi_{n})\Delta x_{n}$$ be a Riemann sum of a function
>   $f$. Explain the notation and provide the assumptions for:
>
> - $\Delta x_{i}$ -
> - $\xi_{i}$ -
> - $f(xi_{i})$ -
> - $n$ -
> - $f$ is -

Can someone help me solve this theory task?

My attempt following the same order:

- $\Delta x_{i} = x_{i} - x_{i - 1}$ - partition of equal size, the length of subinterval
- $\xi_{i} \in [x_{i-1}, x_{i}]$
- $f(xi_{i}) - $ no idea
- $n $ is a number of subintervals
- f is continuous (?)

Can someone help me fix it? The text book left little space to fill, so I expect something basic is required from me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the $Δx_i$ need not have equal length. The partition of the interval $[a,b]$ is given by the points $x_i$ with
$$
a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b.
$$
Yes to $\xi_i\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ and $f(\xi_i)$ being the function values.

There is nothing more to this sum, and all these properties come from the "Riemann" in "Riemann sum".

---

If you want the discussion to extend to the Riemann integral, then you need to add the bounded total variation of $f$ and that the maximal interval length of the subdivision goes to zero.

---

As to the $\xi_i$, Riemann starts his exploration of the integral with a continuously differentiable function $F$ and the mean value theorem
$$
\frac{F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})}{x_i-x_{i-1}}=F'(\xi_i)
$$
for some $\xi_i\in (x_{i-1},x_i)$. In reversing this he found
$$
F(b)-F(a)=\sum_{i=1}^n F'(\xi_i)Δx_i.
$$
Then he turned this around and asked for the condition that, replacing $F'$ with $f$, these sums for infinitesimal partitions will all give the same result in the limit of the partition sub-interval lengths going to zero.

See chapter 4 in [Bernhard Riemann (1867): "Ueber die Darstellbarkeit einer Function durch eine trigonometrische Reihe."](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Trig/)

Comment: Would you tell me what is the $\xi_{i}$?

Comment: These are midpoints, added section to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that $f(xi_{i})$ means $f(\xi_i)$, the value of $f$ at the point $\xi_i.$

$f$ should be Riemann - integrable.

The rest of your answers is o.k.